# freezing user interface c# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

I have a question. Did exists function which disabling all controls at interface? I have a lot of controls and I don`t want do this control after control. I writing a program in WinForms. 
Thanks for helps

Comment: You can disable the containing control: If you disable a form, all controls on that form are disabled, too. If you disable a `GroupBox` or a `TabPage` or  a `Panel` or whatever, all controls contained by them are disabled, too.

Comment: Exactly I want to disable form. Is there this function?

Comment: Every `Control` has a property `Enabled`. If you set this to `false`, the control is disabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure you can, in your Form code behind just write:

```
this.Enabled = false;
```

In the point you want to disable the WHOLE interface. Be careful though, this will prevent even the window from closing using the "X" button.
To prevent that you could just simply move all the controls in your interface inside a Container (like a Panel, GroupBox or whatever), name it (e.g. Panel1) and then use `Panel1.Enable = false` to disable that container together with all his childrens.

Comment: But I want to disable form after click on button. How can I get to this form?

Comment: After double clicking your button to make the event appear in the code behind just paste the code line inside the method like this:
  `private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Enabled = false;
        }
`

Comment: It was so simple...I was thinking that "this.Enabled" disable my button, not form.

Comment: Glad I could help :)